# jQuery UI datepicker not working right with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in MVC. I have used jQuery datepicker on my "Date" control.The jquery code for calling datepicker is given below:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
     });
```

My DateTime Partialview is :

```
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value, new { id = Model.Name, name = Model.Name, @class = "date", @readonly = true })
```

and my DateTimeViewModel properties are :

```
    public string Name { get; set; }

   public DateTime? Value { get; set; }
```

I am using this partial view in a form. Once i completely fill up my form and click on submit, the focus again goes to my datepicker to again pick up the date. It happens again and again and my form become unable to submit. 
I debug this control on chrome and the i noticed that date is not valid as given below:-

```
    <input class="ff date hasDatepicker input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Value must be a date." name="Fields[Lea_ex1_47].Value" readonly="True" type="text" value="" id="dp1369308655980">
```

**EDIT**
Sorry for mentioning it late but i also observed it now. My datepicker  taking the date from 1 to 12 of each month only. That is: Out of 30/31 days it will take the date from 1 to 12 (validate true) and other 13 to 31 giving validation error(validate false).

Kindly give me reason why this is happening? and how can i get rid of this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why do you have `readonly = true`?

Comment: Based on your edit, it's definitely the date format. Check my answer for an explanation and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

#### It's probably this part:

```
{ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }
```

That's not the default way .NET displays a date, so jQuery might not able to parse it. You need to make sure the day comes before the month, and the year is 2 digits.

**Edit:** After reading your edit about the control failing when the day is greater than 12, this is definitely causing that. However, the issues I mentioned below might still cause problems after you've fixed the date format.

#### Other potential problems:

You're setting a `readonly` HTML attribute, and I don't know why you would do that:

```
@readonly = true
```

This will either do nothing or suppress the datepicker from popping up.

Lastly, I notice you're setting the name and ID by hand:

```
id = Model.Name, name = Model.Name
```

That's the editor for `Model.Value`, so why are you connecting it to `Model.Name`? Does anything else in your page have the same ID? Does any other form field have the same name? If so, it's likely to break things on both the client and the server. You don't even need to specify those; the MVC helper method can do it for you.

#### What to do:

First of all, annotate your ViewModel as some have suggested, but make sure the format is right:

```
[UIHint("DateTime")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Value { get; set; }
```

That should fix it, but consider also removing the `id`, `name`, and `readonly` attributes from your Razor code completely.

If you're using HTML5, one thing that *might* help is using `EditorFor` instead of `TextBoxFor`. That should cause it to use the HTML5 `DateTime` input type. jQuery-UI shouldn't have any trouble handling TextBoxes, but it can't hurt.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Value, new { @class = "date" })
```

Comment: The EditorFor option for dates doesn't let you use HTML attributes to set the class - you'll need to create a custom HTML helper. http://evonet.com.au/asp-net-mvc-outlook-styled-appointment-form-with-jquery-date-and-time-picker/

Answer (score 2):

using `UIHint` easy to set Datepicker

```
[UIHint("DateTime")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Due Date")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Value{ get; set; }
```

Add **DateTime.cshtml** file in this path **Shared/EditorTemplates**

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime>
@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.Value), new { placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" })
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBox("", null, new { placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" })
}
@{
    string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    string id = name.Replace(".", "_");
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#@id").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No change in the issue while trying your aproach

Answer (score 0):

Can you try annotating your view-model property like:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Value { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I'm reformatting the value of the textbox datepicker during submit so it will format back to mm/dd/yy.

```
$('#submit').submit(function() {

var dateTypeVar = $('#txtDateBirth').datepicker('getDate');
var oldFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', dateTypeVar);
                  $('#txtDateBirth').val(oldFormat);
});
```

when postback mvc will be able to know now the format.

Hope this helps